# In AWS Codepipeline, how do I assign a proper role name to allow a stack deployment via CloudFormation?

Tags: amazon-web-services, devops, aws-cloudformation

So, I am creating a pipeline and when I go to add a deploy stage to create a stack with CloudFormation, I get this error when I try to attach a role name:

"The role name is invalid. Check that the specified role exists and can be assumed by AWS CloudFormation."

The role exists, and I have gone into "Trust Relationship" and made CodePipeline a trusted entity. I am using the ARN as the role name. Any help would be much appreciated. Thanks!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In the "Trust Relationship" it is actually CloudFormation that needs to be the trusted entity, not CodePipeline.

Comment: Yes you're correct, this is the role CloudFormation runs with. There's documentation on how to configure a CloudFormation role [here](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/using-iam-servicerole.html). Thanks for using CodePipeline!

Comment: Which policies should I attach to this role?